# How can i access the date picker with their class and then id

Tags: jquery, grails, datepicker, gsp

I am using three date-picker of bootstrap
which is using the following code to initiate layout and plugin

```
   <script> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    // initiate layout and plugins 
    $('.date-picker').datepicker({ 
    rtl : Metronic.isRTL(), 
    autoclose : true 
    }); 

    }); 
    </script>
```

How can i access the date picker with their id
as i have a date picker with id birthdate
and i want to set it's enddate without affecting other date pickers
the code for birth date date picker is as foillows

```
<MyUI:datePicker  id="birthDate" name="birthDate"
        label="${message(code: 'BP.birthDate.label', default: 'Birth Date')}"
        required="true"
        value="${BP?.birthDate ? BPInstance?.birthDate?.format('yyyy-MM-dd') : new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')}"
        labelCol="4" elementCol="8" />
```

Please someone help

Comment: what do you have and what do you need, your question is unclear

Comment: @madalinivascu l have three date-picker from  which i only want to set the        endDate:'+0d', for one date picker ...

Comment: then what is the problem you have 3 date-pickers with UNIQUE ids to select from

Comment: @madalin ivascu yes but I am unable to get the id from the class ...  I am trying to access $('.myClass #myId') but unable to load the dates in the date picker

Comment: what do you mean by "get the id from the class"?

Comment: @madalinivascu Means i only want to make the enddate modification in  the birthdate datepicker and the common class for all datepicker is date-picker, so i want to get the id of birthdate from the class date-picker... sorry but i am newbie to jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access only your "birthday" field with

```
$('#birthDate').datepicker({ //...
```

The other datepickers should stay untouched.

If you don't want to work with the ID you have to use something like this, but you have to know on which "position" the "birthDate"-Field is (check if the id is birthDate)... I think you won't get around using the ID.

```
$('.date-picker').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer helped me .